# boolean masking to delete columns contain false in python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one value DataFrame `vdf`:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

and one boolean DataFrame `bdf`:

```
      0      1     2
0  True  False  True
1  True   True  True
```

or code (just edited):

```
import pandas as pd
vdf = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
bdf = pd.DataFrame([[True,False,True],[True,True,True]])
```

I would like to use `bdf` as a boolean masking to delete  columns in `vdf` whose corresponding column in `bdf` contain `False`. In this example, the second and the third columns should be deleted. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What are the outputs of `print(vdf)` and `print(bdf)`?

Comment: Shouldn't the third column be deleted as well?

Comment: if this is a pandas question, you should add the tag

Comment: thank you all for your quick help. yes, i made a mistake in my original post, the third col should be delete as well. i also add the code for vdf and bdf.

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean indexing from `pd.DataFrame.all`:

```
print(vdf.loc[:, bdf.all()])
```

Output:

```
   0  2
0  1  3
1  4  6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
vdf = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
bdf = pd.DataFrame([[True,False,True],[True,True,False]])
print(vdf.where(bdf).dropna(axis=1))
```

And as output get:

```
   0
0  1
1  4
```